# How to fix heap space when increasing node size on a spot instance?

Tags: java, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins

We have been using EC2 Windows spot instance as Jenkins slaves, however, when increasing the size from M5d2XLarge to M5d4XLarge (in an attempt to overcome memory issues in some builds), those fail to be created.

I attempted to set Java Opts Xms and Xmx as part of the init script, however, the error is unchanged. I've read that WinRM may be the issue, but I have a hard time connecting that with the node size increase.

This is the expected log results (from M5d2XLarge)

```
WinRM service responded. Waiting for WinRM service to stabilize on EC2 (Dev-US-East-1) - Windows Server 2019 Docker (i-xxxxxxxxxx)
WinRM should now be ok on EC2 (Dev-US-East-1) - Windows Server 2019 Docker (i-xxxxxxxxxx)
Connected with WinRM.
Creating tmp directory if it does not exist
Executing init script

C:\Users\Administrator>if not exist C:\Jenkins mkdir C:\Jenkins 
init script ran successfully
remoting.jar sent remotely. Bootstrapping it
Launching via WinRM:java  -jar C:\Windows\Temp\remoting.jar -workDir C:\Jenkins
Both error and output logs will be printed to C:\Jenkins\remoting
```

However, right after "Launching via WinRM", it fails due to a garbage collector issue (from M5d4XLarge):

```
init script ran successfully remoting.jar sent remotely. Bootstrapping it 
Launching via WinRM:java -jar C:\Windows\Temp\remoting.jar -workDir C:\Jenkins 
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to allocate 512384KB bitmaps for parallel garbage collection for the requested 16396288KB heap.
Ouch:
java.io.EOFException: unexpected stream termination
```

Comment: Can you check available memory on the instance? The error indicates the memory allocation for the garbage collection could not be satisfied.

Comment: I would suggest adding the following flags to your existing Xms and Xmx options: -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintNMTStatistics -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -noverify

This will show you how much memory was actually allocated. Also the JVM might be competing with other processes on the instance, so you might not get all the memory you ask for

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the script that runs the `remoting.jar`. Modify this line that runs jar to

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar C:\Windows\Temp\remoting.jar -workDir C:\Jenkins
```